# resolve this php fatal error on a plugin for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a wordpress critical error and my debug log shows the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sw_core/inc/options/options.php:656
Stack trace:
#0 /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): SW_Options->_options_page_html('')
#1 /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action('appearance_page...')
#4 /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-admin/themes.php(10): require_once('/home/audiocomp...')
#5 {main}
thrown in /home/audiocompe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sw_core/inc/options/options.php on line 656

The full code from the plugin is available here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GM4ydGdlOUBr7fLXByCxXz0ISs-L4jb/view?usp=sharing

I'm trying to open the theme options menu to adjust settings for my wordpress site but it brings a critical error message.

I'm not a php expert so i hardly understand more than comments on php files. I have adjusted memory limits to beyond recommended just in case and i have also deactivated all plugins and only activated the said plugins but still brings the issue.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the plugin? If so, have you notified the plugin author of the error?

Comment: Report it to the plugin maintainer in the first instance. We cannot help fix the specific error without a [mre] _within your question_ (external links to code are not allowed). See also [ask]

Comment: I have and they are still unresponsive yet am time bound

Comment: here's the sections of code from the file where the error is caught:  
   
   echo '<h2 id="sw-opts-heading">'.get_admin_page_title().'</h2>';
   
   echo isset($this->args['intro_text']) ? $this->args['intro_text'] : '';
  
   do_action('sw-opts-page-before-form-'.$this->args['opt_name']);
  
   echo '<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sw-options-form">';
   
   settings_fields($this->args['opt_name'].'_group');
  
   $this->options['last_tab'] = (isset($_GET['tab']) && !get_transient('sw-opts-saved'))?$_GET['tab']: 1;  (this is line 656)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have code to share please [edit] your question and make it actually readable

Answer (score 0):

It seems that line `echo isset($this->args['intro_text']) ? $this->args['intro_text'] : '';` is responsible for that critical error. It seems that $this->args['intro_text'] is not beeing set anywhere. Try to comment that line and wait for an update and/or open a support ticket in the plugin dev's website.